# Ajax call doesnt work on heroku with Large Amount of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, heroku

On Localhost every thing works fine but problem occur when I am deploying code on heroku.

This is simple Ajax call that I am using in my application.
I am using AJAX to send some data to server for processing.
When I add large amount of data to the request then it get failed.
If I send less data with AJAX request,its working fine.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'Ajax.php',
    data:"data to send",
    type:'POST',
    success: function(data) {
           console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("failed");
    }
});
```

Can anyone suggest me why this is happing???

Answer (score 0):

Heroku only allows 30 seconds for a request before it times out.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

> When this happens the router will terminate the request if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete. The timeout countdown begins when the request leaves the router. The request must then be processed in the dyno by your application, and then a response delivered back to the router within 30 seconds to avoid the timeout.

Answer (score -1):

it has absolutely got to do with the system memory usage especially in a screnerio where you would be parsing a alot of JSON objects to and fro!

Oh wait! not only JSON data, but any type of data(large in size ) using POST/GET method can result in failure because many JS oriented framework like nodejs still returns them as objects at the end!